# DRF: Not showing the url in the api interface

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple view

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

and in the urls

```
path("hello_world/",hello_world,name="hello_world")
```

But I dont see it in the browser

[image]

Which urls are shown here and which are not

Comment: would be nice to know if this was available with out using viewsets, or a way to implement things in a functional way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all of your APIs in /api path, Try using [Viewsets and routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)